# How to replace the characters in substring, including escape characters, with the character 'X'?

Tags: regex, perl, escaping, substring

I'd like to replace a substring (including escape characters) within a given string (including escape characters) in a perl script. If possible with regexp.

**Input:**

```
abcdefg hijkl: (mnop-qrst) uvwx
aabbccd deeff: (gghh-iijj) kkll
aaabbbc ccddd: (eeef-ffgg) ghhh
```

**Replacement string examples:**

```
ijkl:
gghh-iijj
ccddd: (eeef-ffgg)
```

**Output:**

```
abcdefg hXXXX: (mnop-qrst) uvwx
aabbccd deeff: (XXXX-XXXX) kkll
aaabbbc XXXXX: (XXXX-XXXX) ghhh
```

I didn't find anything except the article "Is there a way to replace a substring with a same amount of X characters the length of it?", but there are no escape characters.
The regexp `$s =~ s/(\Q$pattern\E)/'X' x length $1/e;` works for any alphanumeric replacement string, but not if it is containing special characters like `()=,.-:;*`

In the example above, both, the input and the replacement string can contain special characters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve `<<<`

Comment: OK, you've specified a replacement string of `(eeef-ffgg)` - but want it replaced with `(XXXXXXXXX)`? So I take it you want different treatment of stuff in brackets?

Comment: I have a given replacement string "ccddd: (eeef-ffgg)". If the text is something else like "aaddd: (eeef-ffgg)" it should not replace anything. No special threatment for stuff in brackets. I just want perl to look out for the exact same replacement string in one input line. If it founds a result, it should replace anything except special characters and blanks with a X.

Comment: @lycos: What do you call ` *special character*? Why does `ccddd: (eeef-ffgg)` get replaced by `XXXXX: (XXXXXXXXX)` and not `XXXXX: (XXXX-XXXX)`? Why are parentheses and colons special while hyphens are not? Is there anything other than letters and numbers that isn't *special*?

Comment: @ Borodion: Hyphens should have been special characters too. I corrected the above example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

Here's a solution that allows any whitespace in the pattern to match any amount of whitespace in the target string. Note that, to do this, I've had to escape the non-word characters manually, so `\Q`...`\E` aren't needed any more

Note that the last pattern has many spaces between `ccddd:` and `(eeef-ffgg)` but it correctly matches a single space in the string

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @patterns = (
  'ijkl:',
  'gghh-iijj',
  'ccddd:            (eeef-ffgg)',
);

# Build and compile the regex
my $pattern = join '|', map {
  my $item = $_;
  $item =~ s/([^\w\s])/\\$1/g;
  $item =~ s/\s+/\\s+/g;
  $item;
} @patterns;
$pattern = qr/$pattern/;

while ( my $s = <DATA> ) {
  $s =~ s/($pattern)/$1 =~ tr{a-zA-Z0-9}{X}r/eg;
  print $s;
}

__DATA__
abcdefg hijkl: (mnop-qrst) uvwx
aabbccd deeff: (gghh-iijj) kkll
aaabbbc ccddd: (eeef-ffgg) ghhh
```

#### output

```
abcdefg hXXXX: (mnop-qrst) uvwx
aabbccd deeff: (XXXX-XXXX) kkll
aaabbbc XXXXX: (XXXX-XXXX) ghhh
```

---

#### Original post

All that is necessary is to replace

```
s/(\Q$pattern\E)/'X' x length $1/e
```

with

```
s/(\Q$pattern\E)/$1 =~ tr{a-zA-Z0-9}{X}r/e
```

Here's a demonstration. Note that the `/r` modifier requires Perl v5.14 or better

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.014;

my @matches = (
  'ijkl:',
  'gghh-iijj',
  'ccddd: (eeef-ffgg)',
);

while ( my $s = <DATA> ) {
  $s =~ s/(\Q$_\E)/$1 =~ tr{a-zA-Z0-9}{X}r/e for @matches;
  print $s;
}

__DATA__
abcdefg hijkl: (mnop-qrst) uvwx
aabbccd deeff: (gghh-iijj) kkll
aaabbbc ccddd: (eeef-ffgg) ghhh
```

#### output

```
abcdefg hXXXX: (mnop-qrst) uvwx
aabbccd deeff: (XXXX-XXXX) kkll
aaabbbc XXXXX: (XXXX-XXXX) ghhh
```

Answer (score 2):

The trick here I would suggest, is to pre-generate your regex patterns.

```
use strict;
use warnings;


my @replace_strings = qw ( ijkl:
    mnop-qrst
    hijkl: );

my %replace = map { $_ => "X" x length($_) } @replace_strings;

my $replace_regex = join( "|", map {quotemeta} @replace_strings );
$replace_regex = qr/($replace_regex)/;

while (<DATA>) {
    s/$replace_regex/$replace{$1}/g;
    print;
}

 __DATA__
 abcdefg hijkl: (mnop-qrst) uvwx
```

We:

- use a list of 'replacement strings'.
- use map to generate the substitutions ( X x length )
- Generate a regex to match the 'search'
- then use that to apply the 'replace'

This thus prints:

```
abcdefg XXXXXX (XXXXXXXXX) uvwx
```

You could use a similar technique.

Following on from comments - it looks like you want to define some strings, and just replace the text within them.

So how about something like this:

```
my %replace = map { $_ => ($_ =~ s/\w/X/gr) } @replace_strings;
```

Which (on your source data) gives:

```
abcdefg hXXXX: (mnop-qrst) uvwx
aabbccd deeff: (XXXX-XXXX) kkll
aaabbbc XXXXX: (XXXX-XXXX) ghhh
```

(You can add `-` into the pattern if you want to replace that too).

Comment: This will replace the escape characters too. Is there a solution without removing the escape characters?

If you use this input data:
__DATA__
abcdefg hijkl: (mnop-qrst) uvwx
aabbccd deeff: (gghh-iijj) kkll
aaabbbc ccddd: (eeef-ffgg) ghhh

and this replace strings:
ijkl:
gghh-iijj
ccddd: (eeef-ffgg) );

Comment: The `quotemeta` bit should take care of that for you. It escapes special characters for use in your regex. But if it's replacing _just_ letters, then `tr` should do the job.

Comment: I edited the examples above to describe it further. When I use your example including the quotemeta bit, the last line looks like this aaabbbc XXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXX ghhh instead of aaabbbc XXXXX: (XXXXXXXXX) ghhh.

Comment: How does that one look?

Comment: That works fine. Is there a possibility to get it working without matching the amount of whitespaces? If the replacement string e.g. has multiple blanks between the values or less blanks than the input?

Comment: Almost certainly. Might be worth opening another question for that though.